# Use of Validation Pipe with class-validator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly use my validation pipe and class-validator on an API call.

I have a DTO with class-validator decorators that is behaving as expected. However, I'd like to leverage the 'skipMissingProperties' to ignore validation against things that aren't there ('name' for example in the screenshots).

My intent is to be able to have a simple DTO that uses a number of decorators and to skip validation on those that aren't present.

Unfortunately, my use of skipMissingProperties seems incorrect as providing this option still throws validation errors from within the DTO.

**How do I use the validation-pipe skipMissingProperties option along with class-validator decorators for the ones that do get passed in?**

With the following code, if I make an update request with other parameters but exclude 'name' from the body, the class validator throws errors from the DTO level.

[Validation Pipe on Controller Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In9yR.png)

[UpdateViewDTO's decorators Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErpM1.png)

API Controller Endpoint:

```
    @Put(':viewId')
    public async updateView(
        @Req() request: RequestExtended,
        @Param('viewId') viewId: string,
        @Body(new ValidationPipe({ skipMissingProperties: true })) updateView: UpdateViewDto)
        : Promise<View> {

        // Do some API stuff    

       }
```

UpdateViewDTO:

```
export class UpdateViewDto {
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(1, {
        message: LanguageElements.VIEW_NAME_REQUIRED_ERROR_MSG,
    })
    @MaxLength(50, {
        message: LanguageElements.VIEW_NAME_TOO_LONG_ERROR_MSG,
    })
    public readonly name?: string;

    // Other properties 
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and it works for me. Can you include the error message and the body from your put request?

Comment: Have you tried using `@IsOptional()` decorator in the DTO?

Answer (score 2):

In your `main.ts`, you can add `skipMissingProperties: true` right into the ValidationPipe.

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      skipMissingProperties: true,
      exceptionFactory: (errors: ValidationError[]) => {
        return new BadRequestException(errors[0].constraints);
      },
    }),
  );
```